# MongoDB failover when 2 nodes of a 3 node replicaset go down

Tags: mongodb

I need to setup a mongo replicaset on two data centers.

For the sake of testing, I setup a replicaset of 3 nodes, thinking of putting 2 nodes on the local site - Primary and a secondary, and on the other site another standby.

However, if I take down the Primary and one of the standby's, the remaining standby stays as secondary, and is not promoted to become a Primary, like I expected.

Reading about it in other questions here, looke like the only solution is to use an arbiter on a third site, which is quite problematic.

As a temporary solution - is there a way to force this standalone secondary to become a primary?

Answer (score 1):

In order to elect a PRIMARY the majority of all members must be up.

2 out of 3 nodes is not the majority. Typically the data center itself does not crash, usually you "only" lose the connection to a data center.

You can to following.

Put 2 nodes in first data center, and 1 node it second data center. In this setup the first data center acts as primary and must not fail! The second data center may fail.

Another setup is to put one node in each data center and an [ARBITER](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/) on - a different site. This "different site" does not need to be a full-blown data center, the MongoDB ARBITER process is a very light process and does not store any data, so it could be a small host somewhere in your IT network. Of course, it must have connection to both data centers.